# Same BASE64 encoded String for different byte arrays

Tags: java, oop, hash

The following code accepts a File object and creates a BasicFile object using it.

```
package code.CustomFiles.File;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.DigestInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class BasicFile {
    public String hash;
    public File file;

    BasicFile(File f){
        file = f;
        try{
            compute_hash();
        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            this.hash = "NOSUCHALGO";
        }
    }

    BasicFile(String filename, long size, String hash) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(filename);
        f.createNewFile();
        RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(f,"rw");
        r.setLength(size);
        r.close();
        this.file=f;
        this.hash=hash;
    }

    public void compute_hash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        try(InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath());
            DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is,md)){
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        this.hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);
        System.out.println(digest+" "+hash);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Filepath: "+file+"\nHash: "+hash+"\n";
    }

}
```

Output for multiple calls to `BasicFile(File)` constructor:-

```
[B@3abe666c 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@61e4d4fe 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@7dd92a4a 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@349dbe9b 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@6446bac9 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@23c2c19b 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@177d34d3 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
[B@4ecd39c1 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
```

I'm creating multiple BasicFile objects using `BasicFile(File)` constructor but all seem to have the same BASE64 encoded String as output. I don't understand why?

Comment: Have you checked what is in `digest` before Base64 encoding it?

Comment: Ohh. I'll get to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc (my emphasis):

> To complete the message digest computation, call one of the digest methods on the associated message digest ***after your calls to one of this digest input stream's read methods.***

You create the `DigestInputStream` but never read anything from it.

Answer (score 1):

> but all seem to have the same BASE64 encoded String as output. I don't
>   understand why?

You are getting the same base64 string printed on the console because your source digest string is the same. Your source digest string is the same in all the 5 calls to your constructor because even though you are reading the file, you are not really doing anything with its content.

You need to get the message digest from the digest input stream that you have created from your file.

```
MessageDigest str = dis.getMessageDigest();
this.hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(str);
```